# Angular Universal error ReferenceError: MouseEvent is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, runtime-error

I am using angular universal to render ssr, while using angular cli command : npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr , i am getting error.

using Angular8

```
/home/xyz/projects/my-app/dist/server/main.js:139925
Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__metadata"])("design:paramtypes", [MouseEvent, HTMLElement]),
                                                                               ^

ReferenceError: MouseEvent is not defined
    at Module.UPO+ (/home/xyz/projects/my-app/dist/server/main.js:139925:84)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! patient-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the patient-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vijay/.npm/_logs/2019-10-18T07_30_11_791Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side code like `Document`, `Window`, `localstorage`, `MouseEvent` etc will not exist while running in the Universal mode of your angular application as your first page will be rendering on the server.

So If in your code any such piece of code present then you need to wrap your client side code in `platformBrowser` like this -

```
import { ..., PLATFORM_ID, ... } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';


constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
){
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
       // MouseEvent code
    }
}
```

Comment: whereever you have used your `mouse` events or any client side events.

Comment: When we use localstorage will the error say localstorage or will it still say Mouse event?

Comment: it  will say localstorage.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Still the same exception.